# didAnimateRoation toInterfaceorientation - detect when rotation is finished?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

There is a delegate methode willAnimateRotation toInterfaceorientation, which is called right before the interface performs its rotate animation. But how can I detect when the rotation is finished?
I need something link didAnimateRotation ... but there isn't any delegate methode like that.

How can I call a methode as soon as the rotate animation is done? Without using a timed delay :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:"?

Documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: